# Detect full screen exit for inline video player in html5 to trigger angular event

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I am displaying a video in HTML 5 using the inline player, and I want to trigger an event that closes the video player and call a function in my angular application as soon as the full screen is exited.

Video player component:

```
<div [hidden]="!isVideoPlayerVisible">
    <video (ended)="VideoEnded()" (webkitfullscreenchange)="HideVideo()" #videoPlayer webkit-playsinline playsinline">
      <source [src]="videoDetails.source" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Function that needs to be called:

```
  public HideVideo(): void { }
```

The `-webkit-fullscreenchange` works on the web, but when I use the app on my iPhone, it does not trigger the `-webkit-fullscreenchange` event so the component in my angular app never gets called.

Does anyone know of a solution or event that will pick up if the full-screen mode is exited on IOS?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it's a known bug in ios. The whole HTML video element is still a big mess. You can try the following:

```
<video (webkitpresentationmodechanged)="toggleVideo(videoPlayer)" #videoPlayer ...>

public toggleVideo(video: HTMLVideoElement): void {
  if (video.webkitDisplayingFullscreen) {
    this.HideVideo();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem i found the best way to get around this is to not have the full screen on your video and disable the controls on the video element and put your own in and use the [Full-screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

```
<div id="video-player">
   <video id="video-player-display" ...></video>
   <div class="controlls">
       <a onclick="handleFullscreenChange();">F</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can then use the full-screen API on the video-player div

```
document.getElementById("video-player").requestFullscreen();
```

You can then use the full-screen API event [`Element.onfullscreenchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/onfullscreenchange)
as an example using the HTML above

```
var player = document.getElementById("video-player")
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("video-player-display");
player.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", fullscreenChanged);
videoPlayer.addEventListener("ended", playerEnded);

function handleFullscreenChange(){
    if(document.fullscreenElement == player){
        document.exitFullscreen();
    }else{
        player.requestFullscreen();
    }
}

function playerEnded(evt){
    // player has ended exit fullscreen
    if(document.fullscreenElement == player){
        do
    }
}

function fullscreenChanged(evt){
   // fullscreen has changed evt will contain details
}
```